# Source code is not complete because "JS is disabled in your browser"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a python code to, at first, get a full source code of a web page to later scrape it. But when I try to get the source code - I see the aforementioned message ("If you're seeing this message, that means JavaScript has been disabled on your browser, please enable JS to make this app work") with partial html code. Also when I click F12 to see 'elements' the entire code appears meanwhile, pressing Cntrl + U to view the source code yields the same result as getting it with the below mentioned py script

```
source = requests.get(link).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml').prettify()
```

I've seen similar questions to mine but none of them had a satisfactory solution, for example, it was recommended to use selenium to open a new web page and then to work with it, but it would take additional time. JS is enabled in my browser

Comment: It's every bit as complete as what your browser is sent; your browser just modifies that content after it's loaded by running JavaScript. If running JavaScript isn't an acceptable solution to you, you should try to reverse-engineer what that javascript does and implement it yourself in Python. We'd need to have a specific site named in the question before we could even _start_ to do that for you (though a question requesting it would be too broad to be on-topic).

Comment: As a rule, if every preexisting question on a given topic has had an unsatisfactory answer, if you want a _more_ satisfactory answer to your instance, you need to include details that distinguishes the question from those preexisting ones for which no satisfactory answer was possible. (If you only need this to work for sites that use a particular API to retrieve the desired content, f/e, that allows new and different solutions, like implementing that API yourself). If you just ask the same question again, you should expect to get just the same answer again.

Answer (score 1):

It is as you have seen on the other answers, you have to use selenium (or another browser automation tool) to enable javascript rendering. The web page you are trying to access uses client side rendering, which means that the first thing it sends when you access the url is a bunch of javascript code. Then the browser executes the javascript code to create the DOM of the web page.

You are saying that javascript is enabled in the browser but that has nothing to do with your python code. The library you are using `requests` is sending a HTTP GET request to the server to fetch the web page, and the server replies as it would to any other request with the javascript that knows how to render the web page. That's why you need something like selenium, that runs a browser instead of doing a simple HTTP request.

Comment: K, I'll try seleniun then. But it would open a new window each time I'd need to get something as simple as title, right? Not too convenient

Comment: Selenium can run headless; there's not necessarily any "window" involved.